# Is this an exercise of the US Supreme Court’s original jurisdiction?

Tags: us-supreme-court

I was checking the US Supreme Court’s website for recent opinions and came across one for [State of Montana v. State of Wyoming and State of North Dakota](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/17pdf/137orig_new_2cp3.pdf). This opinion looks very different than the others I’ve read in the past. Specifically:

- The case was based on a “Bill of Complaint,” not a writ of certiorari, which is what I’m more used to seeing.
- The case references a “Special Master,” a term I’ve never seen before.
- The opinion is not signed, not even “Per Curiam.”
- The opinion states a “Decree,” which is quite different than the structure I’m used to seeing.
- The case number is “137, Orig.,” which seems to be a different numbering system than what’s typically used.

I’ve been trying to Google these terms to see what they mean, but I’m having trouble finding anything on them.

I know that the US Supreme Court has original jurisdiction in cases between states. Is this an exercise of that jurisdiction? If not, what exactly is this type of opinion?

Comment: Yes. Cases involving one U.S. state suing one or more other U.S. states are part of the U.S. Supreme Court's original jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. States, when litigating among one another, file bills of complaint such as the one you linked to in your question.

A [special master](https://www.mediate.com/articles/kellerC.cfm) is usually a court appointee whose job it is to assist with making sure the judgment is carried out properly. This could take the form in appointing a special master to take over a police department's operations in the wake of civil rights rulings against it for corruption, racism, etc. Another example is they can be sent to make evidentiary rulings at a deposition on the spot.

Comment: In SCOTUS original jurisdiction practice, a "special master" acts basically as a magistrate judge in a district court to take evidence from the parties and supervise pre-trial procedures, who then presents the evidence collected to the Supreme Court for consideration, sometimes with a non-binding recommendation concerning how it should rule on the matter.

Comment: When Vermont sued New Hampshire in 1915 over details of the boundary, the court appointed a special master who was a lawyer from Kentucky who wrote a long report (more than 200 pages, I think?) on the history of the boundary going back to 1664. The court decided the case in 1933.

Comment: @ohwilleke:  Please inform us, if you will, what the jurisdiction or corpus of law a "district" court occupies...  And maybe while you at it, you can tell us about these "circuit" courts and what jurisdiction they occupy.

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen Those are separate questions. But, a U.S. District Court is basically the primary federal trial court that handles federal question cases, cases with a diversity of citizenship, and cases with U.S. government parties. The U.S. Courts of Appeal for the various circuits hear appeals from U.S. District Courts (and a handful of administrative agencies and specialized federal courts).